# Lightswitch HTMLClient does not start browser on Visual Studio "Start" button

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have been going nuts trying to figure out why my Lightswitch HTML Client won't start the browser when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 10 so that means the Edge browser is present. Lightswitch can't start Edge. After spending all day uninstalling, reinstalling, etc. I stumble across the solution.

The default browser for VS 2015 is Edge. I was able to reset the default browser by creating an Asp.net app and making it the start-up project. I was then able to use the Start button and select IE.

Now, when Lightswitch is set back as the start-up it remembers and starts IE.